# content search, using the 2 lines template, error when using PublishedDateOWSDATE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-search-web-part

I wanted to do something really simple. Content search web part on a blog that only displays blog title and published date (PublishedDateOWSDATE).

When I put it as the second line, I get an error

Object does not support property or method 'indexof' (corerender: ----item-twolines.js)

I would have enough to place the creation date (which would suffice) but at that point nothing is shown.

Content search web part was supposed to be easier to use than content query, while I see you always need massive coding to get it right

Comment: You configured it as a Managed Property Mapping in the Content Search Webpart properties ? I'm not sure but you can try using the display name for the field instead, SharePoint can be very ambiguous about that.

Comment: PublishedDateOWSDATE is in the dropdown, usually the items in the dropdown that have OWS in the name are already mapped. I have no problem putting the body of the message (bodyowsmtxt) and the post author (which I do not need), but I am not able to place other fields I would prefer (published date or blog categories)

Comment: It's really weird, because Managed Properties on items that don't have values in the crawled properties are just empty and should be "retrieved" fine from search. Are you sure it's a standard Search WP and there's no other processing going on ? Do you have access to the ULS logs of the server to see if it's a SP internal error ? In that case, it may be worth looking around for that specifically or filing a bug report with MS.

Comment: May also be worth checking your search results don't return unexpected items that may not have the PublishedDate you're using.

Comment: it is a standard search web part. I tried to build another template (with 3 lines of text instead of 2) but I was unsuccessful. Unfortunately there are no proper guides for non-developers that can only copy-paste. So I am stuck with the 2 lines. I can't put body since it's too much space, I can't put a 'summary' because I am not able to, and even published date seems out of reach.

Comment: Strange thing is that it's supposed to work :p. You're getting an unexpected error, your best bet is to find a work around or submit a bug report to microsoft (or maybe ask on their forums ?).

Comment: so you are telling me that if you do as I did, you will get the error too?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I previously placed the render html tag on the line so it was not working with simple text dates.